# Type of handleSubmit parameter in react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have a TypeScript error in `handleSubmit` function.

1. I'm retrieving `handleSubmit` function via `useForm`:

```js
const {handleSubmit, control, watch, reset} = useForm()
```

2. I'm difining submit function:

```js
const submit = (data: { file: File, crop: Area }) => {
    onSubmit(data.file, data.crop)  // onSubmit is passed from parent component
}
```

3. I pass `handleSubmit` in `onSubmit` prop of `Form` component

```js
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
    // registering form fields here
</Form>
```

4. Got the following TypeScript error:

```
 Argument of type '(data: {    file: File;    crop: Area;}) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SubmitHandler<FieldValues>'.
[1]   Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
[1]     Type '{ [x: string]: any; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ file: File; crop: Area; }': file, crop  TS2345
```

If i pass `handleSubmit` like this everything works fine.

```js
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit as any)}></Form>
```

But i'm trying not to use `any` in my project. So if anyone could explain how should i type parameter for `handleSubmit` function i will aprecciate it. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just add the same type as you add to the `submit()` function's `data`, to the `useForm` hook.

So in your example, you can just make a new type:

```
type Data = { 
  file: File; 
  crop: Area;
}
```

and pass it to both, `submit()` function:

```
const submit = (data: Data) => {
// ...
```

and `useForm()` hook:

```
const {handleSubmit, control, watch, reset} = useForm<Data>()
```

Then it should work :)

As I understand it, type provided to the `submit()`'s data gives information about typing only to the `submit()` function.

But because this function is also passed down as an argument, to the `handleSubmit()`, `handleSubmit()` needs to know about the type of passed `submit()`'s data. And we can let it know about this type, simply by providing it to the `useForm` hook.

Answer (score 2):

A more complete example might look something like this:

```
const formSchema = z.object({
  title: z.string(),
})

type FormData = z.infer<typeof formSchema>

const formOptions: UseFormProps<FormData> = {
  resolver: ...,
  defaultValues: ...,
}

const { handleSubmit } = useForm<FormData>(formOptions)
```

Though it's a bit more verbose, the nice thing about this is you'll have typing on your defaultValues as well as the incoming data values in your form submit handler. I hope that helps!